# How to configure redirection to index page with spring boot and zuul proxy for SPA app?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, proxy

I try to use spring boot and angular spa app. I need to proxy some requests to another server. I've configured zuul proxy with this configuration

```
zuul.routes.api.path=/api/**
zuul.ignored-patterns=/api/products/**, /api/products-meta, /api/invoices, /api/products
zuul.routes.api.url=http://another-api-server/
```

It works perfectly in my case, some API are provided by my app, some by another server.

Next one I want to configure redirecting to the index page when user tries to access to my app via direct link, for example, `http://localhost/products/1`

For this case, I used this IndexController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class IndexController {
        @RequestMapping("/**")
        public String index() {
            return "forward:/index.html";
        }
    }
```

But I got this error message
[image: White label error]

And this stack trace
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/vdzundza/9ceb6827abca8b345ab909aea61d14ce)

My main app class

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class Ng2bootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Ng2bootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiGatewayFilter simpleFilter() {
        return new ApiGatewayFilter();
    }
}
```

ApiGatewayFilter just used for logging proxy requests, nothing else.

```
public class ApiGatewayFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiGatewayFilter.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        log.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

        return null;
    }
}
```